# Как исправить вставку \n в поле для ввода при нажатии на клавишу Enter на телефоне?

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня есть edittext в программе, который используется для того чтобы пользователь вводил текст. Так получается что при нажатии на клавишу enter как-то вставляется символ `\n` и текст с этим символом отправляется на сервер откуда его потом можно вытащить. Так вот вопрос - как и что нужно сделать, чтобы текст нормально переносился на новую строку в textView после получения отправленного текста с сервера, потому что с `\n` текст отображается как одна линия хотя я нажимал на клавишу enter и текст переносился на новую строку нормально.
Вот как выглядит все на данный момент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и там после каждой буквы где встречается \n это нажатие на клавишу enter.

### UPDATE

Вот как выглядит ответ сервера:

```
"f\\nf\\nf\\nf\\nf\\nf\\nf\\nf\\n"
```

вот что мне удалось из этого сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот как я этого добился:

```
 body = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getBody().replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

Comment: а что значит нормально переносился?

Comment: @yno7, обновил вопрос, так лучше?

Comment: На изображении текст после пересылки?

Comment: да, но в логах на сервер такое уже идет, я спрашивал то на сервере все нормально и такого добавить не могут.

Comment: Посмотрите что именно приходит с сервера. Предположу что-то типа "j\\nu" вместо "j\nu".

Comment: Странно. У меня текст "f\nf\nf\nf\nf\nf\nf\nf\n" отобразился так как вы желаете, то есть каждая новая f на новой строке?!

Comment: @iramm, у меня там два слеша стоит перед каждой n может быть в этом проблема?

Comment: Если программно убрать везде лишний слэш, то все отобразится как надо

Comment: да я уже размышляю над этим вопросом)

Comment: @iramm, это получается нужно каждый лишний слэш заместить на пустую строку? просто я пробовал сделать через replaceAll() но там эту проблемную строку нельзя убрать.

Comment: Попробуйте `.replace("\\n", "\n")`.

Comment: @eugeneek, а не, помогло, но тогда теги html остаются в тексте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение для задачи нашел, но довольно нестандартное)) В общем в чем проблема - на сервер при написании тела сообщения я отправляю такое:

```
"body":"privet\nprivet\nptivet"
```

дальше вот что я получаю:

```
"body": "privet\\nprivet\\nptivet"
```

Я долго думал и решил что в принципи можно заменить двойной слэш на `<\br>` и вот как это делается:

```
tvBody.setText(stripHtml(body.replace("\\n", "<\\br>")));
```

не знаю правильно ли это я сделал или нет, но я добился того что нужно. Может быть я криво сделал, но надеюсь что это поможет кому-то.